# if isset Not Writing To Database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, isset

I have an if isset statement that fires when my site receives approval from my merchant account api after a form is submitted. Everything seems to work except for the order details from the form getting written to my database. Here is the code for my form:

```
            <form id="input-form" class="form-inline" action="" method="post">
            <?php

            if($error <> '') {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">',$error,'</div>';
            }
            ?>


            <div id="makepayment">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="order_fname">First Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" style="width: 273px;" type="text" name="order_fname" id="order_fname" value="<?php echo $user['user_fname']; ?>" placeholder="First Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="order_lname">Last Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" style="width: 273px;" type="text" name="order_lname" id="order_lname" value="<?php echo $user['user_lname']; ?>" placeholder="Last Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="order_phone">Primary Phone</label>
                <input class="form-control" style="width: 273px;" type="text" name="order_phone" id="order_phone" value="<?php echo $user['user_phone']; ?>" placeholder="Phone Number" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="order_cell">Cell Phone</label>
                <input class="form-control" style="width: 273px;" type="text" name="order_cell" id="order_cell" value="<?php echo $user['user_cell']; ?>" placeholder="Cell Phone" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="order_email">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" style="width: 273px;" type="text" name="order_email" id="order_email" value="<?php echo $user['user_email']; ?>" placeholder="Email Address" />
            </div><br/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="form-group" style="width:100% !important">
                <label for="company_id">Property Information</label><br/>
                <br/>
                <input id="company_id" type="hidden" id="company_id" name="company_id"  value="<?php echo $company['company_id']; ?>" /> 
                <input id="company_name" type="hidden" id="company_name" name="company_name"  value="<?php echo $company['company_name']; ?>" /> 
                <div class="property">
                <strong><?php echo $company['company_name']; ?></strong><br/>
                <?php echo $company['company_street']; ?><br/>
                <?php echo $company['company_city']; ?>, <?php echo $company['company_state']; ?> <?php echo $company['company_zip']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div><br/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="order_cc">Card Number</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="ssl_card_number" id="ssl_card_number" style="width:100% !important" />
            </div><br/>
                <div class="clear"></div>
```

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="order_code">Security Code</label>
                <input class="form-control" style="width: 75px;" type="text" name="order_code" id="order_code" placeholder="ex:123" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="order_customernumber">Customer Number</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width: 75px;" name="order_customernumber" id="order_customernumber" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="order_invoicenumber">Invoice Number</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width: 75px;" name="order_invoicenumber" id="order_invoicenumber" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="order_amount">Payment Amount</label>
                $ <input class="form-control" type="text" style="width: 100px" name="ssl_amount" id="ssl_amount" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="width:100% !important">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Here is my if isset statement that fires if the api sends back an approval code. I know that part works because it does this action when I put in my card info and throws the proper error when I put in fake info.

```
if(isset($response['ssl_result_message']) && $response['ssl_result_message'] == "APPROVAL") {
        //If transaction successful write to database
         $userid = $session['user_id'];

         $addOrderSQL = "
    INSERT INTO orders (
        user_id,
        company_id,
        order_fname,
        order_lname,
        order_phone,
        order_cell,
        order_email,
        company_name,
        order_customernumber,
        order_invoicenumber,
        order_amount

    )
    VALUES (
        '$userid',
        '$_POST[company_id]',
        '$_POST[order_fname]',
        '$_POST[order_lname]',
        '$_POST[order_phone]',
        '$_POST[order_cell]',
        '$_POST[order_email]',
        '$_POST[company_name]',
        '$_POST[order_customernumber]',
        '$_POST[order_invoicenumber]',
        '$_POST[ssl_amount]'
    )";


    $firstname= $_POST['order_fname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['order_lname'];
    $invoice = $_POST['order_invoicenumber'];
    $customernum = $_POST['order_customernumber'];
    $property = $_POST['company_name'];
    $ordertotal = $_POST['ssl_amount'];

    /* ------------------------------------------------- 
        Send Email to Administrator
    ------------------------------------------------- */
    $to       = "web@abcprintingink.com";
    $subject  = "Payment for Customer # ". $customernum;
    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: webmaster@turfmastersct.com" . "\r\n" .
        "Reply-To: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
        "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    $message  = "<p>A customer has completed a payment. Here are the payment details:</p>
        Customer Name: ". $firstname ." ". $lastname ."<br/>
        Customer #: ". $customernum ."<br/>
        Invoice #: ". $invoice ."<br/>
        Property: ". $property ."<br/> 
        Payment Amount: $". $ordertotal; 

    // Send it.
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        //once executed queries redirect user
        header('Location: /payments/orders.php');


        exit;
    }

    elseif(isset($response['errorCode'])) {
        $error = 'Your credit card has been declined';
    }
    else {
        $error = 'Failed to process your payment';
    }
```

The form is communicating with the api, I get a response from it and I can see the payment details post to my demo account. The isset statement fires, I get the email that it sends and it redirects me to the `orders.php` page like it's supposed to. It just doesn't write to the database. You can see my form and you can see the fields I am writing to my database. All those fields exist in the database itself. Am I missing something here?

Comment: $session ? what are you using?

Comment: Where do you actually call the database and execute the query, $addOrderSQL ?  Did you check your error logs to see what is happening ?

Comment: You only store your query in a variable but not run any query function (e.g mysqli_query) to save in database

Comment: I connect to the database through a file called `db-connect.php` which is included in my template. It connects to the database here `$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);`

Comment: My error log shows `mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/turfmasters/public_html/payments/orders/order.payment.php on line 18` which is `$company = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getCompany);`. This is part of `$getCompanySQL = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE company_id=".$_GET['company_id'];
    $getCompany = mysqli_query($db, $getCompanySQL);
    $company = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getCompany);` where the database pulls in the company information. It obviously gets the info because it shows the company name in the email I get.

Answer (score 1):

You never run the $addOrderSQL query.

See [mysqli_query()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp) to do this.

Comment: as far as I understand it, my isset should run the query. It works on every other page but this one and they are all structured the same way. The only difference is this isset statement looks for authorization from my api rather than simply the form submitting

Comment: I'm not sure why it would, I would't reccomend relying on an isset to execute a query if it does work